# ReactJS App keeps reloading after React Router DOM

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to implement router to my reactjs app and after setting things up, my page wont even load, it just keeps reloading in my browser till it crashs.

This is my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
class App extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Content
          job={this.state.header_infos[0].job}
          college={this.state.header_infos[0].college}
        />
        <Skills />
        <Portfolio />
        <Timeline />
        <Footer />
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} /> /* if it clicks in my logo, redirect to mainpage */
          <Route path="/monitoria" component={Monitoria} /> /* if clicks in Monitoria from Navbar, redirects to Monitoria component. */
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my Header.js with my navbar

```
import React from "react";
import "../sass/Header.scss";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className="">
      <NavLink exact to="/">
        <h1 className="logo">Logo</h1>
      </NavLink>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" className="nav-toggle" />
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li className="menu-item">
            <NavLink to="/monitoria">Monitoria</NavLink>
          </li>
          <a className="btn-rounded" href="#">
            <li className="menu-item">Fale comigo</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <label htmlFor="nav-toggle" className="nav-toggle-label">
        <span />
      </label>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

If i remove React Router DOM from my App.js my page works just fine. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Component `App` cannot be inside `<Route exact path="/" component={App} />` because `App` is the parent component that contains Route in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, in app.js, you are assigning class App into a route that is contained in the App class.